Compare two datafile with same structure and identify detail differences PySpark
I have two DF like image below:
I want compare two DF in order to identify how detail differences between two table(add rows, delete rows, change values in columns...).
Note that my DF don't have any keys. In addition, these columns may contains both character and numeric values. Beside that, columns may not only are disorder but also have duplicate value, null value.
For example expectation i draw below:

Orange color represents to values change in specific cell column
Yellow color represents to deleted rows
Blue color represents to new rows

Help me some ways I can check efficiently.


Not sure if this is possible without any means to identify the rows (e.g. with a key column). How do you decide if a row is deleted or if fields have been changed? Take for example the row CDO/5.9/10/0 from table A. In your example it is deleted. If none of the columns contains a key how do you decide that the row ALLP/100/1/0 from table B isn't the same row with all columns changed but the last one?

Its hard to differentiate Delete and Modified without Key Columns. CDO 5.9 10 could be classified under Modified also.

Yah, i know. But suppose that I don't care about is that deleted or changed. Is there anyway to identify what is different change between DF_A and DF_B ?
